# Disable delete sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like also to prevent user to delete some of the sheets.
How to do that in excel 2010?
`Application.CommandBars("Ply")` doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by protecting the structure of the workbook (I think that option is under Protection in the *Review* tab)

I believe this is the only way to actually prevent the user deleting a sheet, although it can be possible to find out using VBA Workbook events that a sheet has been deleted - [See this answer by Excel MVP Colo on MerExcel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/5340-worksheet-delete-event.html#post24123)